# Как сделать проверку по ID? Javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Делаю одно страничный сайт, на главной странице меню из списка, каждый li взял в ссылку, на href поставил id блока, который будет открываться при клике на какую либо кнопку меню, изначально эти блоки стоят display none, кликнешь например на кнопку portfolio список li уезжает влево, и открывается блок portfolio. Вот вопрос, как сделать проверку по id, если кликнул по portfolio открывается блок portfolio. Можно каждой ссылке дать свой id и написать скрипт отдельно для каждого блока, чтобы срабатывал при клике по ссылке, но может можно компактный код написать, через проверку по id.

Comment: конечно можно

Comment: в где помощь?

Comment: там же где и вопрос ... ))

Comment: @Mackay, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#menu li a').click(
    function()
    {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем что-то проверять, поставьте на клик по ссылке событие onclick, и перед тем как открыть следующий блок просто закройте все блоки, а потом открывайте тот на который сработало событие, простите кода нет, ибо не знаю что у вас там, будет исходный код, будет нормальная помощь!